# Update matrixInput in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to update the matrix input based on user-input values for the first row when the button "fill matrix" is pushed. The matrix is updated correctly (as printed), but the input fields do not change accordingly. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyIncubator)  #for matrixInput

df <- data.frame(matrix(c("0","0"), 1, 2))
colnames(df) <- c("Input1", "Input2")

shinyUI(

    fluidPage(

        matrixInput( inputId = "matrix",
            label = "matrixLabels", 
            data = df),
        actionButton(inputId = "fillMatrix", label = "Fill matrix"),

        verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "matrix")

    )                

)
```

server.R

```
serverFunction <- function(input, output, session){


updateMatrixInput <- function(session, inputId, label = NULL, data = NULL) {

    message <- list(label = label, data = data)
    session$sendInputMessage(inputId, message)

}

observeEvent(input$fillMatrix, {

      oldMatrix <- input$matrix
      firstRow <- oldMatrix[1,]
      currentProportions <- sum( oldMatrix[,2], na.rm = TRUE )
      isMissing <- which( is.na(oldMatrix[,2]) )
      nRows <- nrow(oldMatrix)

      oldMatrix[2:nRows,1] <- firstRow[1]
      oldMatrix[isMissing,2] <- (1 - currentProportions) / length(isMissing)

      output$matrix <- renderPrint({ oldMatrix })
      updateMatrixInput(session = session, inputId = "matrix", 
          label = "matrixLabels", 
          data = oldMatrix)

      })

}

serverFunction
```